# Laravel passport certificates format seems invalid RSA

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, rsa, laravel-passport

Hello I am using passport for my auth.
It creates 2 files:

*oauth-private.key*

and

*oauth-public.key*

Problmen is since I am using them to sign jwt external authentication it seems that these format are somewhat incorrect, or at least not compliant.

I think they (while being .key) are in .pem format as the beginning would suggest:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MII
```

Yet i see pem key usually starting with:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I think this RSA here indicates that the files is encoded with RSA X.509

I tried: **openssl x509 -in .... -text -noout** and gives me wrong format, but I don't know if this makes sense.

My question is:

Can I force passport to use rsa encryption on keys? Or maybe can I use another public - private pair that I can generate using a precise alghoritm?

I need some clarifications here. Thank you